# Multiple Server Certificates on WCF ServiceHost

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on a legacy architecture that has a server that has an existing certificate for communication. Multiple existing services in the legacy architecutre use this for communication. I am working on creating a communication channel on a much newer system that is built for scale that will communicate with our old framework. This will be used to perform a phased migration where we rely on the old architecture for a period of time, while still running the old system.

Due to some internal constraints, we can't simply add the existing certificate to the new architecture.  Furthermore, changing the certificate to the new one will require changing every single service that communicates with the server to have retry logic & both certificates. Furthermore, this has the potential to instantly break the old system entirely (as all the services rely on the server to perform - one of the limitations of the old architecture).

So the ideal solution is that the service simply accepts two different certificates for a period of time while we perform the migration. The new services communicate with their certificate and the old services communicate with theirs. Then we can deprecate & decommission the old services

The only way I see to set a certificate is either in config or how we currently do it:

```
host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                                                   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My,
                                                   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                                   thumbprint);
```

Calling this again would overwrite the certificate set on the host. So is there any way that I can add an additional certificate that the server can distinguish between and use the appropriate certificate for communication with the client when it receives a connection?

Thanks for your time

Comment: This solution is not feasible, if use certificate verification, the server can only bind one certificate, as you said, if you add two certificates, one of the certificates will be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks, I came to this conclusion as well after much more research - but turns out I did not need it. I misunderstood how the cert encryption worked and thought the client's certificate played a role in tandem with the server certificate.

Answer (score 0):

As Ding Peng mentioned in the comments:

> This solution is not feasible, if use certificate verification, the server can only bind one certificate, as you said, if you add two certificates, one of the certificates will be overwritten.

This is correct, but I was misunderstanding how certificate encryption worked and it was unnecessary to add an additional certificate.

Simply by adding logic to whitelist the client certificate subject names of the new architecture - it was able to authenticate.

I had assumed that if the server certificate did not share the subject name of the client cert, that there would be an issue with authentication & encryption. However, this is not the case and simply whitelisting the new subject name was enough to perform the auth.